# Disable GPS after use on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

Because of energy reasons I want to disable the GPS after retrieving a single location, but for some reason the GPS keeps turned on for over 10 mins.

The code that I use is:

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = accuracy;
geolocator.MovementThreshold = 0;
var position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

Comment: How are you determining that the GPS radio is kept on?

Comment: I see the GPS marker in the bar on the top of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the geolactor after it has given you a position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.
The biggest expense in using GPS can often be turning it on and you can't be sure what else on the device is going to want to use it soon. (This could be native features, other apps the user may switch to or background processes.)
For this reason the OS contains heuristic logic to manage the radios